# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'Chainable<string>'.ts(2345)

Tags: typescript

Trying to write a simple test with TypeScript:

```
describe('client end to end', function(): void {
    it('should display correct title in browser', async function(): Promise<void> {
        assert.strictEqual(cy.title(), 'something');
    });
});
```

Get the error on the `'something'`:

```
Argument of type '"something"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Chainable<string>'.ts(2345)
```

What does this even mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
assert.strictEqual(cy.title().toString(), 'something');
```

Another way to solve it if you

Just realized that the assert is coming from `chai`, which I want to avoid at all costs.

Importing nodes assert via `import * as assert from 'assert';` fixed the issue.

Nodes `assert` does toString() automatically while `chai`'s doesn't.